# Update chord diagram data from JSON in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I have the following 2 functions that creates and draw the a D3 chord diagram of netflow between IP's of our network.

Functon 1 (the one that create the chords diagram)

```
function createChords(jsonURL, containerID, tooltipID, circleID, svgID, valueFormat = 'none'){
    d3.json(jsonURL, function (error, data){
        if(data.length > 2){
            var mpr = chordMpr(data);
            mpr.addValuesToMap('from').setFilter(function (row, a, b){
                return (row.from === a.name && row.to === b.name)
            }).setAccessor(function (recs, a, b){
                if (!recs[0]) return 0;
                return +recs[0].value;
            });
            drawChords(mpr.getMatrix(), mpr.getMap(), containerID, tooltipID, circleID, svgID, valueFormat);
        };
    });
};
```

Function 2 (the one that draws the diagram)

```
function drawChords(matrix, mmap, containerID, tooltipID, circleID, svgID, valueFormat){
var w = 980, h = 800, r1 = h / 2, r0 = r1 - 45;
var fill = d3.scale.category10();
var chord = d3.layout.chord()
    .padding(.00)
    .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
    .sortChords(d3.descending);
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(r0)
    .outerRadius(r0 + 20);

var svg = d3.select("#"+containerID)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", svgID)
    .attr("class", "chord-svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+w+" "+h)
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", circleID)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

svg.append(circleID).attr("r", r0 + 20);
var rdr = chordRdr(matrix, mmap);

chord.matrix(matrix);

var g = svg.selectAll("g.chord-group")
    .data(chord.groups())
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "chord-group")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", function (d){
        d3.select("#"+tooltipID)
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
    });

g.append("svg:path")
    .style("stroke", "none")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
    .attr("d", arc);
    g.append("svg:text")
    .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d){ return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
    .attr("transform", function(d){return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"+"translate(" + (r0 + 26) + ")"+(d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");})
    .text(function(d){if(d.endAngle - d.startAngle<2*Math.PI/180){return ""}else{ return rdr(d).gname;}});

var chordPaths = svg.selectAll("path.chord-diagram")
    .data(chord.chords())
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "chord-diagram")
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.target.index)).darker(); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.target.index); })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(r0))
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        d3.select("#"+tooltipID)
            .style("visibility", "visible")
            .html(chordTip(rdr(d)))
            .style("top", function(){ return (d3.event.pageY)+"px"})
            .style("left", function(){ return (d3.event.pageX + 10)+"px";})
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d){d3.select("#"+tooltipID).style("visibility", "hidden")});

function chordTip(d){
    var p = d3.format(".0%"), q = d3.format("0d");
    if(valueFormat == 'none'){
        return q(d.svalue) + " de <b>" + d.sname + "</b> hacia " + "<b>"+d.tname+"</b>";
    } else if(valueFormat == 'bytes'){
        return bytes_to_human(q(d.svalue)) + " de <b>" + d.sname + "</b> hacia " + "<b>"+d.tname+"</b>";
    } else if(valueFormat == 'abbreviate'){
        return k_formatter(q(d.svalue)) + " pkts de <b>" + d.sname + "</b> hacia " + "<b>"+d.tname+"</b>";
    } else {
        return q(d.svalue) + " de <b>" + d.sname + "</b> hacia " + "<b>"+d.tname+"</b>";
    }
};

function groupTip (d) {
    return d.gname;
};

function mouseover(d, i) {
    d3.select("#"+tooltipID)
        .style("visibility", "visible")
        .html(groupTip(rdr(d)))
        .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 80)+"px"})
        .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 130)+"px";});

    chordPaths.classed("chord-fade", function(p) {
        return p.source.index != i && p.target.index != i;
    });
}
```

}

And finally, I call the function to create my different netflow data charts with this snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
createChords(
    '/ajax/charts/netflow/realtime/records/packets',
    'records-diagram-packets',
    'records-tooltip-packets',
    'records-circle-packets',
    'records-svg-packets',
    'abbreviate'
);
});
```

Actually to update the chart what I do is, clean the containerID div with (containerID).emtpy(); and recall createChords() but what I need is to update the data with new ajax request data from jsonURL with optionally animation transaction.

I tried the solution here http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6bd13f974d6516f3e491 with no luck.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each an every time depend upon the data SVG is newly created. So you have to remove the SVG Before Creation

```
d3.select("Your Id Name or Your Class Name").select("svg").remove();
```

In Your Code, I changed follow as

```
d3.select("#"+containerID).select("svg").remove();
var svg = d3.select("#"+containerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a update function or update your drawChords to update the data and graph and call it from Ajax function. Here is a simple [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8) , which is extension of the example you provided. Build something like this [function](https://gist.github.com/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8#file-index-html-L99). There are numerous examples of d3.js to update graph.

Comment: Yep, I'm following this example but can't find the parts I have to change, for example I have the d3.json function because I need to load the data from the URL, but I don't kow exactly what I have to change to update the existing svg element, and don't create another, because now I have a function called updateChords() that add another svg element, every time the update function is called. Where I'm stucked is in the "make changes" step. I can load another time the data and parse it, but  don't know how to continue.